# AWS CDK - Resource's path part only allow [a-zA-Z0-9:._-], an optional trailing '+'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a GET on :carType/id/:id

I can do it with

```
 const carResource = rootResource.addResource('{carType}').addResource('id').addResource('{id}');
```

but this seems to add a resource for each of the segments?

I really just want to add one resource, but this breaks with the error in the title.

```
 const carResource =  rootResource.addResource('{carType}/id/{id}')
```